# How to configure the printer to stop after the page content is finished , irrespective of the page setup?

Tags: configuration, printing

I'm printing an invoice from the browser and the invoice size may vary.

I've set a page size of 6 inches width and 5 inches height..

Even if my invoice is just 2 lines  it would take up the whole 5 inches height of paper and roll out..

Can i configure it to just stop rolling paper once the print content is finished, so that i can save paper?

I'm using dot matrix printer and rolling paper..

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there is an End Of File mark, form feed, or other command that is triggering the paper to eject.  If you have control over the output file then remove any commands like this, if not, can you "print to file" and post process the file?  If so remove these commands at that point and setup an automated process to do this for you.